# The graph of function $f(x)=a+b\cos (\frac{\pi}2-hx)$ is given, what is the value of $abh$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

The graph of function $f(x)=a+b\cos (\frac{\pi}2-hx)$ at a period is as follow. What is the value of $abh$ ?

$1)\frac43\qquad\qquad2)-\frac43\qquad\qquad3)\frac34\qquad\qquad4)-\frac34$

[image]

I'm not sure how it denotes a period of the function visually I see it is half of the period. anyway, I think period of function is $2\times(\frac{7\pi}2-\frac{-5\pi}2)=12\pi$ . Hence $h$ should be $\frac16$ or $\frac{-1}{6}$ (I'm not sure which one is correct). And because minimum of the function is $-4$, and the concavity of $\cos x$ changed, we can conclude $b=-4$. but I don't know what is the value of $a$ and I'm not sure about the sign of $h$.

Comment: I think its (not to sure) -4/3 because the period is -2 the displacement is -2 and h is 1/3 because (|-5π/2|+7π/2)=2π/6π=1/3

Comment: @allan `:s/period/amplitude` ?

Comment: @LeifMetcalf sorry i didn't do sinusoidal functions in a long time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One oscillation from peak to peak is plotted so this is a full period.

I think this question is wrong:

The period is $6\pi$ so $h=\pm\frac13$. But then the derivatives at $-\frac{5\pi}2$ and $\frac{7\pi}2$ cannot be zero, which the picture suggests they are.

Maybe they meant to write $f(x)=a+b\cos\left(\frac\pi6-hx\right)$? That has the plot:

[image: plot]

when $a=-2$, $b=-2$, $h=\frac13$.